# Missing kableExtra formating in rmarkdown ioslides

Tags: r, knitr, ioslides, kableextra, kable

I'm trying to include `kableExtra` table in my ioslides in RStudio. I get the tables correctly, however simple formatting from the [vignette examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) seems to be gone.

````
---
title: "Tables"
output:
  ioslides_presentation: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]    
```

## No styling

```{r t1}
dt %>%
  kable("html")   
```

## Styling

```{r t2}
dt %>%
  kable("html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed", full_width = F, position = "center"))
```
````

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: The presentation output formats have default pandoc templates, which are overriding the style applied to your slides. You could build your own `ioslides` template to suit your needs or just the *CSS* you require for your tables.

Comment: You could use `webshot` as in [this](https://gist.github.com/magnusnissel/9b3ce0f9c869af7a8abb80633ef9180b) approach to make your table an image if building the CSS or pandoc template are too involved for you.

Comment: Thanks @KevinArseneau could be a solution. Having troubles running `webshot` example but will report back if I have some progress.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to update the kableextra to 0.9.0 or above. Starting from this version, it will automatically load required css into the slides environment.

Update:
If it still doesn't work, you can force kableExtra to load the css for you by

```
options("kableExtra.html.bsTable" = T)
```

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/news/news.html under kableExtra 0.9.0

Comment: I have the same problem. Your solution doesn't work for me, though. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by including the bootstrap CSS, which are used by kableExtra:

```
output:
  ioslides_presentation: 
    css: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```